# VBA Code to match values in multiple columns and then transpose corresponding values to separate columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, multiple-columns, transpose

My VBA skills are novice at best and I'm unaware as to how to approach this efficiently.

**Goal**: To match Case ID #'s *AND* the Client Name (One case ID # can have multiple clients) and if they both match, then pull the Q response from the Response column based on the Question # (Question column)

I have 2 source files and one destination file. I have managed to extract all necessary data from source file 1(SF1) to the destination File (DF).

I need to pull out data from SF2 to the DF.

The SF2 Data is structured as follows:

```
Case ID    Client Name   Question #   Response
10095      ABS            0.1          50
10095      ABS            0.2          100
10095      ABS            0.3          0
10095      ZZZ            0.1          0
10095      ZZZ            0.2          40
10095      ZZZ            0.3          99
29999      OVFLW          0.1          100
```

The DF is structured/would look like as the following:

```
CASE ID   Client Name   0.1    0.2    0.3   
10095     ABS           50     100    0
10095     ZZZ           0      40     99
29999     OVFLW         100
```

The code I have is able get all of the above, but cannot account for the extra variable being the Client Name to match against ***in addition*** to the CASE ID. Any ideas/suggestions would be welcome.

Thank you in advance. Code below:

Option Explicit

```
Public Sub GrabKpiData3()

Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol, foundrow As Long, foundcol As Long

Dim macrobook As Workbook
Dim macrosheet As Worksheet

Set macrobook = ThisWorkbook
Set macrosheet = macrobook.Worksheets("Macro")

'source
Set sht = Workbooks("SourceFile2.csv").Worksheets("SF2")

'destination
Set sht2 = Workbooks("MacroFile.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

k = 2

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If sht2.Cells(k, 1).Value = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        'the below 2 rows grab different date values present within SF2. This would change based on match criteria requiring Case ID + Client name
        sht2.Cells(k, 16).Value = sht.Cells(i, 2).Value
        sht2.Cells(k, 17).Value = sht.Cells(i, 3).Value


        lastcol = sht2.Cells(1, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'captures responses for 0.1
        sht2.Cells(k, 18).Value = sht.Cells(i, 6).Value

        i = i + 1

        'captures responses for 0.2
        sht2.Cells(k, 19).Value = sht.Cells(i, 6).Value

        i = i + 1

        'captures responses for 0.3
        sht2.Cells(k, 20).Value = sht.Cells(i, 6).Value

        i = i + 1

        sht2.Cells(k, 21).Value = sht.Cells(i, 6).Value

        i = i + 1

        sht2.Cells(k, 22).Value = sht.Cells(i, 6).Value

        k = k + 1

    Else

On Error Resume Next

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need VBA? This might be possible with a formula.

Comment: VBA would be necessary unfortunately :( there's other data involved + for possible expansion to other things in the future.

Comment: It doesn't look like you understand how `On Error Resume Next` works.  You should probably remove it, and only use it when absolutely required (which is more rare than you think).  You also need an entire 2nd for loop for `k`.  The whole `k = k +1` isn't right.

Comment: @VBAWARD, you should select which ever answer below helped the most.  That way the question won't remain open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a normal VBA solution which should work (although the SQL is nice, you may run into some compatibility/version issues)...

```
Set sht = Worksheets("SF2")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("DF")
SrcLastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
DestLastRow = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To SrcLastRow
    ' Find the row with a matching Case ID/Client Name
    For k = 2 To DestLastRow
        If sht2.Cells(k, 1).Value = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value And _
           sht2.Cells(k, 2).Value = sht.Cells(i, 2).Value Then _
            Exit For
    Next
    ' Updated - Forgot to add new records...
    If k > DestLastRow Then ' it's a new CaseID/Client Name, so add it
        sht2.Cells(k, 1).Value = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value
        sht2.Cells(k, 2).Value = sht.Cells(i, 2).Value
        DestLastRow = DestLastRow + 1
    End If

    q = 3 ' Starting column for Questions, look for a matching question/header (or blank)
    Do Until sht2.Cells(1, q).Value = sht.Cells(i, 3).Value Or sht2.Cells(1, q).Value = vbNullString
        q = q + 1
    Loop
    ' Write the header for the next question, if it doesn't exist
    If sht2.Cells(1, q).Value = vbNullString Then sht2.Cells(1, q).Value = sht.Cells(i, 3).Value

    ' Write the Response
    sht2.Cells(k, q).Value = sht.Cells(i, 4).Value
Next
```

Update: Tested and fixed code to create new headers.

Comment: Version issues aside, if you needed to change the logic of how to join the data in the future, that is *much* easier (and understandable too!) with something that implements SQL for doing Set based comparisons.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I've been trying to work with this and its working for the most part. The problem I'm running into in trying to amend the code to work for my situation is the need portion that adds in new records. Since SF2 is only pulling in data based on the Case ID's *already* present in DF, this portion of the code seems to add in a series of rows to the bottom of DF and is causing the data to appear incorrectly. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @Profex: For further context, what would be ideal is (in simpler language)
DF Macro checks SF2 to find matching CASE ID and CLIENT NAME, and if both are found, then it returns the RESPONSE to the appropriate Question # (which are headings in DF, but part of the row its checking in SF2). I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Profex: I've modified as such below. However, it creates one row at the bottom and I found that its cycling data in this field for which there is NO CASE ID or CLIENT NAME. Any idea what's wrong with my code? EDIT: sorry I cant paste the code into this box. let me know if there's another way i could show this to you.

Comment: @VBAWARD, you may want to add a check that the CaseID/Client Name are not blank, before processing any other data with the `For i ...Next` loop.  Other then that, make sure that you increment `DestLastRow` whenever you add a new row.  It's hard to say for sure, without seeing your updated code & data/file that you are using.

Comment: SrcLastRow = srcsht.Cells(srcsht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
DestLastRow = destsht.Cells(destsht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To SrcLastRow
        For k = 2 To DestLastRow
        If destsht.Cells(k, 1).Value = srcsht.Cells(i, 1).Value And _
           destsht.Cells(k, 9).Value = srcsht.Cells(i, 2).Value Then _
            Exit For
    Next

Comment: q = 18 
    Do Until destsht.Cells(1, q).Value = srcsht.Cells(i, 5).Value Or destsht.Cells(1, q).Value = vbNullString
        q = q + 1
    Loop
    destsht.Cells(k, q).Value = srcsht.Cells(i, 7).Value
    destsht.Cells(k, 15).Value = srcsht.Cells(i, 3).Value
    destsht.Cells(k, 16).Value = srcsht.Cells(i, 4).Value
    
Next

Comment: @Profex: hope that helps? sorry i didnt know how else to paste it in. apologies in advance.

Comment: @VBAWARD, you could just append your question next time.  It looks like you referenced an old version of my answer.  Take a look at my code again; you missed the `If k > DestLastRow Then` part, where you add the new line and increment `DestLastRow`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL to accomplish this joining of data. I've mirrored my data after yours, I called my sheets SF2 and DF to correspond with your examples. Add a reference to `Microsoft Active X Data Object version 2.x` for this to work correctly.

```
Sub GetJoinedData()
    Dim conn        As ADODB.connection: Set conn = New ADODB.connection
    Dim rs          As ADODB.Recordset: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim outputsheet As Worksheet: Set outputsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i           As Long: i = 1

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
              ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';"

    'My data is on two sheets named DF and SF2
    SQL = "Select [DF$].*, [SF2$].[Response] from [DF$] " & _
          "INNER JOIN [SF2$] on [SF2$].[Case ID] = [DF$].[Case ID] " & _
          "and [SF2$].[Client Name] = [DF$].[Client Name]"
    rs.Open SQL, conn, adOpenForwardOnly

    'Add headers
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        outputsheet.Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    'Dump the data
    outputsheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

---

Update

I think I misunderstood your first ask. What I now understand is you are taking the results in `SF2` and transforming (a Pivot) to what is in `DF`. I've updated my code to do that.

It should multiple allow for new questions when they are added, and you retain the column headers along the way. Hope it helps.

```
Sub GetJoinedData()
    Dim conn        As ADODB.Connection: Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs          As ADODB.Recordset: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim outputsheet As Worksheet: Set outputsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DF")
    Dim i           As Long: i = 1

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
              ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';"

    'My data is on two sheets named DF and SF2
    Sql = "TRANSFORM Max(response) " & _
          "SELECT [case id], [Client Name] " & _
          "FROM [SF2$] " & _
          "GROUP BY [case id], [Client Name] " & _
          "PIVOT [Question #];"

    rs.Open Sql, conn, adOpenForwardOnly

    'Add headers
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        outputsheet.Cells(1, i).Value = Replace$(fld.Name, "_", ".") 'Fix a SQL formatting issue where _ exists
        i = i + 1
    Next

    'Dump the data
    outputsheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

Comment: how would i amend this if the two files were separate? for example: I open SourceFile2(SF2) and then open DestionationFile(DF) and run the macro on DF. Do  I need to define the path or anything for it to read from SourceFile2, sheet SF2?

Comment: For this to work as is, all data needs to be in the same workbook, or file. Is there a reason for the data to not be consolidated? Might be needed to pull it all into Excel to do the comparison. Alternatively, you could store the data in something like Access.

Comment: Upon review, this doesn't output what was asked for by the OP.  It has multiple records(lines) for the same Case ID/Client Name.  Plus, the Inner Join limits the table to only the existing Case ID/Client Names in both tables and removes everything else.  It's a much harder problem to solve in SQL, especially if you want to add columns dynamically (i.e. Question 0.4).  It's a nice example of how to use SQL to read data from worksheets, but in the end, it doesn't work.  That being said, I need to fix my answer as well.

Comment: @Profex How would you join 5 tables? 10? 100? That's a whole lotta loops. The other solution isn't well suited for additional scope.

Comment: @RyanWildry, I would just call the routine and pass it the Source and Destination Worksheets; scope/scaling issue addressed. The extra loops aren't that big of a deal (especially compared to the time it takes to open the files). Is it the fastest, No; there are improvements such as reading/writing the data using a variant array, but that would complicate things. I don't think speed is the main issue here.  (FYI, yours is 10x faster if the source files aren't already opened in Excel, mine is 10x faster if they are)

Comment: Both solutions work; the question is which one is easier to understand and maintain.  Will people recognize that `TRANSFORM Max(response)` is going to take the highest score (if multiple entries exist), or that `PIVOT [Question #]` can only use numbers? Doubtful. _FYI, mine will overwrite the response with the latest value._  Also, my solution doesn't require everything to be in one file, which will work out better for processing a folder of files to create a summary file...Either way, hopeful the OP and others can learn from both solutions.